# Can the spamming user Victor be dealt with?

Tags: support, status-completed, spam

[Victor](https://superuser.com/users/128589/victor-stoyanov) seems to keep posting links to Groupdocs.com on every question even remotely related to PDFs or document management. Some recent examples:

- https://superuser.com/questions/43321/document-management-system/413122#413122
- https://superuser.com/questions/41268/how-to-create-a-simple-document-assembly-application-for-word-documents/413116#413116
- [Opening doc files as docx](https://superuser.com/questions/298122/opening-doc-files-as-docx/413113#413113)

According to [this website](http://digitalministry.com/AU/directory/14076/GroupDocs) he (or at least someone with the exact same name) is working for GroupDocs, which would make his posts plain self-promotion. Can someone look into it and deal with him?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for pointing it out! In the future, please just flag one of their posts for moderator attention, and explain what the deal is.

This allows for a more immediate response when the flag queue is handled.

Comment: I did flag his posts, but since it looked like he would just keep deleting the old user that got sent in the box and creating a new one, I thought I'd report it here so perhaps some permanent measures could be employed. Also, I thought the proof that he was associated with the website might be relevant (flagging a post doesn't allow for additional comments to be added).

Comment: Flagging always lets you include a comment. Just don't click the "spam" option, but the "other" field. It's not a problem to bring it up on meta, but in these obvious cases a quick flag will do :)

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, thanks!